# SQL generate random values

Tags: sql

Maybe someone know, how to generate number for same clients?
Let's take that I need to have:

```
|CLIENT|RANDOM_NUMBER|
|     1|       A2D5C4|
|     1|       A2D5C4|
|     2|       A3D5C4|
|     1|       A2D5C4|
```

Thanks for help!
P.S. I'm using SQL developer.

Comment: Which DBMS ?....

Comment: A2D5C4 is not a number

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan - 10671556 http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.htm

Comment: @Vityata, ahh in Hex :) so next question if he want it varchar or int

Answer (score 1):

If your platform has MD5() : (I am using Postgres here, the `::text` is a cast)

---

```
CREATE TABLE the_table
        ( client integer
        );
INSERT INTO the_table(client) VALUES (1),(2),(1),(1);
```

---

```
SELECT client
    , RIGHT(md5( client::text ), 6) AS random_number
FROM the_table
    ;
```

---

Result *here*:

---

```
 client | random_number 
--------+---------------
      1 | 75849b
      2 | 14862c
      1 | 75849b
      1 | 75849b
```

Comment: What happened with the hex from the OP question?

Comment: `MD5()` yields an md5-hash, represented as a hex-string. I use the 6 rightmost characters.

Comment: if you add the creation of the SQL table to the SQL I will upvote :)

Comment: Well, I was *not* thinking as a procedure, but about an expression, using a function, with client as its only argument.